# Как повесить TextChangedListener на EditText

Tags: android, kotlin

Подскажите пож-та как правильно повесить слушателя изменения текста в EditText.
Перемещал код в after, также не работает.
Ставил бряки во все три метода, ни на одном не остановилось приложение.
Но при этом в дебаге видно, что слушатель висит.

```
mBinding.registerInputCode.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                val string = p0.toString()
                if (string.length == 6) {
                    enterCode()
                }
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {

            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

мы живем в мире котлина и если ktx библиотеки подключены, то у нас есть такое прекрасное расширение:

```
mBinding.registerInputCode.doAfterTextChanged { editable ->
//что-то делаем editable это тот самый текст, можно назвать как угодно
}
```

[Вот ссылка на раширения](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx/extensions-list)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я пробовал расширение, также не работает.
Ставлю бряку в блоке if, печатаю в поле и приложение не останавливается.

Comment: а что требуется сделать то? Если  что-то сделать при вводе текста, то эти методы работают отлично.

Comment: У меня судя по  всему проблема где то еще выше, т.к. у меня не работает ни один из вариантов.  Приложил ссылку на гит, если будет время: https://github.com/qk7p/LightPrintV2

Comment: EnterCodeFragment.kt `mBinding = FragmentEnterCodeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)` перенести в `onViewCreated()` и изменить на  `FragmentEnterCodeBinding.bind(view)`должно после этого заработать, если я все верно понял

Comment: Спасибо огромное, лисенер заработал, а вот дальше не работает, но это совсем другая история))

Comment: @DmitryMorozov тогда примите мой ответ, пожалуйста :)